# How do I filter a list of objects using a specific date range on Tray.io?

Tags: automation, lowcode, ipaas, tray.io

I have a list of objects, and I need to filter by a specific field on the objects to make sure each item falls within a specified date.

I don't see this in the Date Time helper

Any suggestions?

I tried looking in the list helper and I didn't see any options there for this type of filter. I also tried looking in the list helper but couldn't find anything that made sense for me there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from a Tray.io expert, but I think you'll need to do this with a script connector.

This snippet gives more info (you can paste it directly in your workflow and then configure it): https://tray.io/documentation/snippets/filter-a-list-of-objects-by-date-range/